# How to use pivot to get 2 columns into a column multiindex in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a data frame with 4 columns (a, b, c, d are column names):

```
df = 
a   b   c    d
1   2   3    4
5   2   7    8
```

Is it possible to use `df.pivot()` to get 2 columns into the column multiindex? The following doesn't work:

```
df.pivot('a', ['b', 'c'])
```

I want

```
b  2
c  3   7
a  
1  4   NA
5  NA  8
```

I know I can use pivot_table to get this done easily (`pd.pivot_table(df, index='a', columns=['b', 'c'])`) but I'm curious about the flexibility of `pivot` as the documentation isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are obviously missing bits of implementation and I think you've found one.  We have work arounds but you are correct, the documentation says that the columns parameter can be an object but nothing seems to work.  I trust @MaxU and @jezrael gave it a good try and none of us seem to be able to get it to work as the documentation says is should.  I call it bug!  I may report it if someone else hasn't already or doesn't before I get to it.

---

That said, I found this, which is bizarre.  I planned on passing a list to the index parameter instead and then transpose.  But instead, the strings `'c'` and `'b'` are used as index values... that isn't at all what I wanted.

What's stranger is this

```
df.pivot(['c', 'b'], 'a', 'd')

a    1    5
b  NaN  8.0
c  4.0  NaN
```

---

Also, this looks fine:

```
df.pivot('a', 'b', 'd')

b  2
a   
1  4
5  8
```

But the error here is confusing

```
print(df.pivot('a', ['b'], 'd'))
```

> ```
> KeyError: 'Level b not found'
> ```

The quest continues...

---

**OP's Own Answer**
*disregard*

Using [**`pivot_table`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

> df.pivot_table(values=None, index=None, columns=None, aggfunc='mean', fill_value=None, margins=False, dropna=True, margins_name='All')

```
df.pivot_table('d', 'a', ['b', 'c'])

b    2     
c    3    7
a          
1  4.0  NaN
5  NaN  8.0
```

Comment: I had this solution in my question though.

Comment: @Zhang18 I know... jezrael already politely pointed that out to me.  I'm working on something more useful :-)

Comment: Can you report the bug on GitHub please and provide a link here? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The closest solution without aggregating is `set_index` + `unstack`:

```
df = df.set_index(['b','c','a'])['d'].unstack([0,1])
print (df)
b    2     
c    3    7
a          
1  4.0  NaN
5  NaN  8.0
```

Solution with `pivot`, but a bit crazy - need create `MultiIndex` and last transpose:

```
df = df.set_index(['b','c'])
df = df.pivot(columns='a')['d'].T
print (df)
b    2     
c    3    7
a          
1  4.0  NaN
5  NaN  8.0
```

Comment: Ok, not implemented. Then what does it mean [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) by saying `columns` can be _a string or object_. What object?

Comment: It's a nice `unstack` solution ++

Comment: Hard question, give me some time.

Comment: I think object means MultiIndex.

Comment: I tried to put a MultiIndex object and it didn't work: `df.pivot('a', pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['b'], ['c']]))`

Comment: @Zhang18 - So I reported it to [pandas github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16578).

Answer (score 2):

we can also use `pd.crosstab`:

```
In [80]: x
Out[80]:
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  2  7  8

In [81]: pd.crosstab(x.a, [x.b, x.c], x.d, aggfunc='mean')
Out[81]:
b    2
c    3    7
a
1  4.0  NaN
5  NaN  8.0
```